# esp32: Doing some math in c++ results in inf

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-c++

I'm currently working on a project and i need to calculate time between to presses of a button and do some calculations on it and then show it on a display. currently I'm only printing it and it only prints `inf` and not a number. here is my code:

```cpp
const int ledPin = 5;
const int btnPin = 33;
unsigned long start_time =1;
unsigned long time_passed;
double current_speed;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(btnPin, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
}

void loop() {
         bool buttonState = digitalRead(btnPin);
        if (buttonState==1){ 
          time_passed = (millis() - start_time); //calculating time between to presses
            if (time_passed > 25){ // checking if button is actually pressed and not hold
            Serial.println(0.35/(time_passed/1000)*3.6); // this outputs "inf"
            }
          start_time = millis(); // resetting time
          }
}
```

Comment: `(time_passed/1000)` is  `0` for `time_passed < 1000` because it uses integer arithmetics

Comment: when you try to understand the result of an operation involving 3 operators you should break it down to steps with 1 operator

Comment: Thank you @463035818_is_not_an_ai . i changed type of `current_time` to double and it worked. I didn't know this because i'm new tp c++ and i used micropython before c++.

Comment: @Seyedmahdimoosavyan *and i used micropython before c++* -- Do not use any other computer language as a model in writing or learning C++.  If you continue to do this, you will end up with 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, and 3) Programs that will look weird to a C++ programmer.  Your attempt violated 1).